# Looking for an event that fires only when user checks a CheckBox

Tags: .net, winforms, events, checkbox

`System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` has two different events that the programmer can handle:

- `SelectionChangeCommitted` - event fires only when the user changes the selected item
- `SelectedIndexChanged` - event is also raised when the selection changes programmatically

Is there something similar for `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`?

Clarification:
I'm looking for an event to handle that won't be fired when I programmatically set the checkbox by calling a statement like `CheckBox.Checked = true`.

Comment: No.  Winforms is fairly unapologetic about it, you can always know when you changed it in your code.  Set a bool flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just handle the `Click` event. Any time a checkbox is clicked, it will be toggled.

```
    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Since changing the `.Checked` property doesn't fire the Click event.

Answer (score 3):

As Control.focused is true only when the user has clicked on the control with the mouse, you can use the following code to respond only when the user checks the checkbox

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBox1.Focused)
    {
        //do ur stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want [this event? (CheckBox.CheckedChanged)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx)

Comment: That event still gets fired when programmtically changing the checkbox. I've clarified the question above.